# How should I set posts for a permanent lean-to horse shelter?

Tags: wood

I'm building a horse shelter that will not be moved and am wondering what my options are for setting the posts.  The horse owner wants to use 4x6 lumber for both posts and beams.

Comment: It depends on the square footage or 1 stall vs more. I have single shelters that are 4×4 posts with gravel packed, on my larger 4 horse shelters I still used 4x4 posts but set them in concrete. Any issues with high wind set the posts on concrete and use hurricane straps to keep the roof in place. I have seen more than a few shelters without a roof after a good storm.

Comment: Pro tip: purchase or find free online blueprints https://www.google.com/search?q=lean+to+horse+shelter+plans